# When disabling open-in-view on spring boot application, can Eclipse or Spring Boot help me find methods that need Transactions?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a fairly new Spring Boot Java application I am working on, that I did not realize had the spring jpa "open-in-view" setting on by default.

I was running into some problems where disabling that setting ended up being the best solution, but now I have come across a couple cases where I was accidentally relying on that.

For example, I had a Service class that was not marked as @Transactions, looping over a lazy-initialized child of one of my entities, before it returned to the controller.

Now this function throws the LazyInitializationException, as expected, because I am not in a transaction.

I have not yet written test cases that provide 100% coverage, is there anything built into Eclipse, or Sprint Tools Suite, or Spring Boot run-time that I can generate some report on, to tell me when classes Annotated with @Entity have function calls made on them in non-transactional method calls?

Any other way to try to identify this, without adding 100% code coverage tests to my application, ore reviewing every method call with a fine-toothed comb?

If there isn't, then I would work on the test cases.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I seriously doubt there exists such a tool. If checking transaction boundary correctness could be done or even helped programmatically, we'd know. You could probably spot simple cases (with heavy assumptions), but as a general solution...nah.

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect, but I did find a way to find the majority of cases for my application using the `Reflections` library.  I ran this as a `@SpringBootTest` test case, and fixes the errors one at a time.

```
@Test
public void testOne() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.base.package",
                        new SubTypesScanner(), 
                          new TypeAnnotationsScanner(),
                          new MemberUsageScanner());

    Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.Entity.class);

    for( Class<?> c: annotated){
        log.debug(c.getSimpleName());
        for( Method m: c.getMethods()){
            if( m.getReturnType().isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class) ){
                checkTransactional(reflections,c, m, 0);
            }
        }
    }
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
}

public static void checkTransactional(Reflections reflections, Class<?> c, Method m, int depth) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    if( depth >64){
        throw new RuntimeException("No Transactional Method Found");
        //return;
    }
    String s = "--";
    Annotation t = null;

    Class<?>[] possibleAnnotations = {
            org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.class,
            javax.transaction.Transactional.class, 
    };

    Annotation[] annotations = m.getAnnotations();
    for( Annotation a: annotations){
        Class<?> aClass = a.annotationType();
        //// handle javax and spring Transactional
        if( aClass.getSimpleName().equals("Transactional")){
            t = a;
            s = "++";
            break;
        }
    }


    String prefix = "";
    for( int i = 0; i < depth; i++){
        prefix = prefix + s;
    }

    log.debug( prefix + " " + c.getCanonicalName() + ":" + m.getName());

    if( t != null ){
        log.trace("This is transactional");
        return;
    }

    Set<Member> callingMembers = reflections.getMethodUsage(m);
    if( callingMembers.size() == 0){
        log.error("Nothing calls this method, if it is a controller, we have a problem" + (c.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class) || c.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)));
        if( (c.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class) || c.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)) ){
            throw new RuntimeException("No transactional method found in call heirrchy before controller"); 
        }
    }
    for( Member usingMember: callingMembers){
        Class<?> callingClass = usingMember.getDeclaringClass();
        List<Method> callingMethods = new ArrayList<Method>();
        if( callingClass != c ){
            for( Method callingClassMethod: callingClass.getMethods()){
                if( callingClassMethod.getName().equals(usingMember.getName())){
                    callingMethods.add(callingClassMethod);
                }
            }   
        }
        if( callingMethods.size() > 2){
            log.error("Two methods call this, manually review");
            for( Method caller: callingMethods){
                log.debug( prefix + "!! " + c.getCanonicalName() + ":" + caller.getName() + ":" + caller.getParameterCount());
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Two methods with same name ( overloading ) call this, manually review"); 

        }
        for( Method caller: callingMethods){
            checkTransactional(reflections, callingClass, caller, depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```